# CSS Comma Usage

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Below is some CSS code.

```
.form-field {min-height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 4px; width: 80px;}
.form-field TEXTAREA, INPUT[type='text'] {position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0px; height: 15px;}
.form-field TEXTAREA {height: 80px;}
```

So every time there is a `input` or `textarea` in the `div.form-field` that css should be applied.

Although anywhere just a `INPUT[type='text']` (even outside the `.form-field`) the css gets applied. How do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.form-field TEXTAREA, .form-field INPUT[type='text']{
```

Answer (score 3):

The comma separates the entire selector. So `.form-field TEXTAREA, INPUT[type='text']` selects `.form-field TEXTAREA` and `INPUT[type='text']`.

What you might be interested in is the [`:matches()` selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches). At present, this is only available in FireFox as the [`:-moz-any()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A-moz-any). That allows you to write:

```
.form-field:-moz-any(TEXTAREA, INPUT[type='text'])
```

However, it's safer just to go with

```
.form-field TEXTAREA, .form-field INPUT[type='text']
```

---

As a side note, HTML tag names should be lowercase. So you should really be using

```
.form-field textarea, .form-field input[type='text']
```

Comment: Claiming dibs on CSS4, I see :P

Comment: oh I see. Thanks couple of things in there I didn't know about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Whoops you wanted OR, ignore this.**

The + "Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E."
Source: [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

```
.form-field TEXTAREA + INPUT[type='text'] {position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0px; height: 15px;}
```